# Reading Column Value based on Row number - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

i am new to excel formulas,
I have the below scenarios, there are 2 sheets in my workbook the first sheet is:

```
ProjectName Primary Secondary
P1  Ajay    Shekar
P2  Rahul   Ajay
P3  Shekar  Rahul
P4  Raj Simran
```

the second sheet is resource Specific let say for Ajay and has a drop down based on ProjectName.
My requirement is When I select the Project name say P1, the second column should populate with the Value 'Primary', if its P2 the value should be 'Secondary' in the Sheet2.
Can anyone Please suggest how can i achieve this solution?

I tried getting Row Number for Matching Project Name but i am not able to get the relvant column number based on Row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(VLOOKUP(B1,'Resource Sheeet'!A:C,2,FALSE)=A1,"Primary",IF(VLOOKUP(B1,'Resource Sheeet'!A:C,3,FALSE)=A1,"Secondary",NA()))`

Resource Name is in cell A1, Project Name is in cell B1.  Just runs 2 VLOOKUPS to see if the name exists in column B or C.  *Only* works if there is only 1 row per project!

If you have more than one row for each project, you could try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!B:B,A1)>0,COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!B:B,A1) & " Primary","") & IF(--COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!B:B,A1)*--COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!C:C,A1)," and ","") & IF(COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!C:C,A1)>0,COUNTIFS('Resource Sheet'!A:A,B1,'Resource Sheet'!C:C,A1) & " Secondary","")
```

Which will list out how many Primary/Seconday matches for the project (e.g. "1 Primary", "1 Primary and 1 Secondary", "3 Secondary", etc)

---

**{EDIT}** *Based on comment below:  This formula will match for any number of columns, but **still** only works for 1 row per project:*

```
=INDEX('Resource Sheet'!$1:$1,1,MATCH(A1,OFFSET('Resource Sheet'!$A$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A)*--('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A=B1)))-1,0,1,COUNTA('Resource Sheet'!1:1)+COUNTBLANK('Resource Sheet'!1:1)),0))
```

> `INDEX('Resource Sheet'!$1:$1,1,MATCH(..))` : This will provide the Header value from Row 1 of the Resource Sheet in the Column number provided by the `MATCH`

That's the simple bit.  Now, `MATCH` is also fairly simple - give it a value (`A1`) and a Row or Column, set the Match-type to `0`, and it will give you which Column/Row in the Row/Column matches the value.

So, we look along the row for the Project.  Do do that, we will use `OFFSET` to make the row-range:

```
OFFSET('Resource Sheet'!$A$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A)*--('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A=B1)))-1,0,1,COUNTA('Resource Sheet'!1:1)+COUNTBLANK('Resource Sheet'!1:1))
```

Breaking it down:

> `Resource Sheet'!$A$1` : This tells us which sheet to look in

--

> `,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A)*--('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A=B1)))-1` : This tells us which row to look at, but I'll explain it later.

--

> `,0,1` : This tells us that we start in Column A ("Move 0 columns right"), and only want 1 row high.

--

> `COUNTA('Resource Sheet'!1:1)+COUNTBLANK('Resource Sheet'!1:1)` : This makes sure we look at the whole row.

--

Now, to explain the last bit, with the `SUMPRODUCT`.  It ends with a `-1`, because from `$A$1` we move `0` rows down to finish on Row 1, or `2` rows down to finish on Row 3, etc.  The `SUMPRODUCT` itself is just to force it to evaluate as an Array Formula - and the formula itself is `MAX(ROW('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A)*--('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A=B1))`

> `MAX` : We want the largest value, because the rows we **don't** want will retun `0`

--

> `ROW('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A)` : This will be an Array for all of the row numbers, `{1,2,3,4...}`

--

> `--('Resource Sheet'!$A:$A=B1)` : The inside bit will create an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` for each row if the value in Column A matches our Project Name.  The `--` converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`  Using your examples above, `P1` would give `{0,1,0,0,0,..}` and `P2` would be `{0,0,1,0,0,..}`.
>   Multiply the 2 arrays together, and for `P1` you get `MAX({0,2,0,0,0,..})` and for `P1` you get `MAX({0,0,3,0,0,..})`

Comment: i was looking  to reach the values from Sheet1 (Primary,Secondary) instead of Hard coding the values in the formula. The Values shoudl be derived from Sheet1 based on Project Name and Resource name

Answer (score 0):

With your dropdown containing the choices (
P1, P2, etc) in A2 you can use this in an adjacent cell.

```
=CHOOSE(MID(A2, 2, 2), "primary", "secondary", "secondary", "secondary", "secondary")
```

[image]